# Trying to loop a switch with an invalid input (C#)

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Anyway I don't know how I'm supposed to go about doing this... in my application I need to have the switch repeat itself if there's an invalid input. All the application does is exit as soon as I enter a different result. Here's my code:

```
string str = Console.ReadLine(); 
char option = char.Parse(str);
//Need to repeat this switch:
switch (option)
{
    case 'N':
        Console.WriteLine("Creating New App...");
        break;
    case 'L':
        Console.WriteLine("Loading App...");
        break;
    case 'O':
        Console.WriteLine("Loading Options...");
        break;
    case 'Q':
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting Application...");
        System.Environment.Exit(1);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        break;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `switch` in a loop

```
bool invalidInput = true;

while (invalidInput)
{
    string str = Console.ReadLine(); 
    char option = char.Parse(str);

    switch (option)
    {
        case 'N':
            Console.WriteLine("Creating New App...");
            invalidInput = false;
            break;
        case 'L':
            Console.WriteLine("Loading App...");
            invalidInput = false;
            break;
        case 'O':
            Console.WriteLine("Loading Options...");
            invalidInput = false;
            break;
        case 'Q':
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting Application...");
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a `while` statement.

```
bool shouldRun = true;

while(shouldRun)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 'N':
            Console.WriteLine("Creating New App...");
            shouldRun = false;
            break;
        case 'L':
            Console.WriteLine("Loading App...");
            shouldRun = false;
            break;
        case 'O':
            Console.WriteLine("Loading Options...");
            shouldRun = false;
            break;
        case 'Q':
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting Application...");
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
            shouldRun = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: @Blucyrik You are welcome. I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the switch you need to use one loop.I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
    bool ExitFlag = true;
    while (ExitFlag)
    {
        ExitFlag = false;
        switch (option)
        {
            case 'N':
                Console.WriteLine("Creating New App...");
                break;
            case 'L':
                Console.WriteLine("Loading App...");
                break;
            case 'O':
                Console.WriteLine("Loading Options...");
                break;
            case 'Q':
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting Application...");
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
                ExitFlag = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Note How It Works**:

Let the `ExitFlag` be a Boolean value that controls the while loop( stop iteration and exit the while when `ExitFlag` is false). and are initialized with `true`. in each time the control enters into the while the flag is set to `false` so that we can avoid setting it false in multiple cases.  The flag will set to `true` only when the `default` case is executed(ie., the invalid output) hence the loop repeats in this condition only.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Goto: label option in C#.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx

```
    ReadAgain:
    string str = Console.ReadLine(); 
    char option = char.Parse(str);

    //The switch itself:
    switch (option)
    {
        case 'N':
            Console.WriteLine("Creating New App...");
            break;
        case 'L':
            Console.WriteLine("Loading App...");
            break;
        case 'O':
            Console.WriteLine("Loading Options...");
            break;
        case 'Q':
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting Application...");
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
            goto ReadAgain;
            break;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Never use `Goto` when you can use a loop ;).

Comment: Can you explain us why Goto is not preferred over a loop?

Comment: In your referred SO discussion, the case was closed as there is no concluded answer because this varies based on opinion and situation. Also the accepted and most rated answer in that page says that Goto is preferred in some cases to get out of deeply nested loops. So based on the situation Goto can also be preferred instead of a loop. 

 In this example I do not understand why I cannot use Goto! Anyway since it is not related to the question of the owner of this case, I let it go.

Comment: How *Goto is preferred in some cases to get out of deeply nested loops* gives a result of *Goto can also be preferred instead of a loop* ???!!! - You can also see that the title of question that make sense enough. In general using `Goto` is a really bad choice instead of emergency cases as described in that SO link answers ;).